# Linearising equations of motion

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, linearization

I have obtained the following equations of motion
$$2\ddot \theta_1 +\ddot \theta_2 \cos(\theta_2-\theta_1) -(\dot \theta_2)^2 \sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)+\frac{2g}{l}\sin(\theta_1)=0$$
and $$\frac{2}{3}\ddot \theta_2 +\ddot \theta_1 \cos(\theta_2-\theta_1) +(\dot \theta_1)^2\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)+\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta_2=0$$

I then proceeded to linearise them and got the following equations

$$2\ddot \theta_1 +\ddot \theta_2+\frac{2g}{l}\theta_1=0$$

and $$\frac{2}{3}\ddot \theta_2 +\ddot \theta_1+\frac{g}{l}\theta_2=0$$
for the following problem [image]

i was wondering if anyone could show me a solution for 6, because i'm stuck and its the last part, i know we need to find the eigenvalues but i'm terrible at writing the equations in matrices.

Comment: i'm really stuck on this problem,

Answer (score 3):

You replace

- $\cos(θ_2−θ_1)$ with $1$
- $(\dot θ_k)^2\sin(θ_2−θ_1)$ and similar higher order terms with $0$
- $\sinθ_k$ with $θ_k$.

and should obtain greatly simplified equations. See also "double-pendulum", as you could replace the bar with two point-masses at the ends. There should be some posts here and elsewhere on that topic.

---

In the end you will get a system $A\ddot θ+Bθ=0$. You could treat this as first order system of dimension $4$,
$$
\pmatrix{\ddot θ\\\dot θ}
=
\pmatrix{0&-A^{-1}B\\I&0}
\pmatrix{\dot θ\\θ}
$$
and solve this via eigen decomposition, or you could directly insert $θ=θ_0e^{i\omega t}$ to get the eigenvalue problem 
$$
(Aω^2-B)θ_0=0\iff (A^{-1}B)θ_0=ω^2θ_0
$$
where you can find the eigenvalues from $\det(Aω^2-B)=0$ without inverting matrices.

Comment: what about $\ddot \theta$ ? or does that stay the same?

Comment: Yes, they stay as they are first order terms. You only remove quadratic and higher order terms.

Comment: so is this correct $$2\ddot \theta_1 +\ddot \theta_2+\frac{2g}{l}\theta_1=0$$ for one of the equations of motion?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: okay so now i've linearised them how do i go about finding the natural frequencies and modes

Comment: any hints for this next part?

Comment: Added a section about it.

Comment: i calculated my eigenvalues to be $$\lambda=\frac{3\pm \sqrt3}{2}\frac{g}{l}$$ is this correct?

Comment: That is looking good.

Comment: What should I do after this bit?

Comment: The next natural step is the computation of the eigenvectors, which are the modes mentioned in the task. You will need to find the real expressions of the found solution, i.e., something in sin and cos.

Comment: do we replace $\lambda$ with $\omega^2$?, and could you show me how to find the eigenvectors because i dont really understand it